# XLForm: Selector of custom cell not calling method

Tags: ios, swift, selector, xlform

I am using XLForm in swift and added some "normal" cells and a custom cell to my form like this:

```
XLFormViewController.cellClassesForRowDescriptorTypes().setObject("MyCell", forKey: "MyCellType")
section = XLFormSectionDescriptor.formSectionWithTitle(NSLocalizedString("Section1Title", comment: "")) as! XLFormSectionDescriptor
        form.addFormSection(section)

row = XLFormRowDescriptor(tag: Tags.Pair, rowType:"MyCellType", title: NSLocalizedString("Pair", comment: ""))
row!.cellConfigAtConfigure["titleLabel.text"] = "hello world"
row!.cellConfigAtConfigure["progressView.hidden"] = true
row!.action.formSelector = #selector(ChestbeltSettingsViewControllerImpl.didTouchButton(_:))
section!.addFormRow(row!)
```

then I implemented `didTouchButton` the following way:

```
func didTouchButton(sender: XLFormRowDescriptor) {
print("didTouchButton")    
switch sender.tag {
    case Tags.ShowHelp:
        print("showHelp")
        break
    case Tags.Pair:
        print("pair")
        break
    default: break
    }

    self.deselectFormRow(sender)
}
```

for the "normal" (not custom) cells the selector works fine, but for my custom cell not even the method is getting called. Does anybody know a possible reason? Thanks

**EDIT:** I solved it by letting my custom cell override `XLFormButtonCell` instead of `XLFormBaseCell`

Comment: try `row!.formSelector` instead of `row!.action.formSelector`

Comment: tried that but got the following error: `Value of type 'XLFormRowDescriptor' has no member 'formSelector'`

Comment: okay i found [this](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm/blob/0db6e546c544057a7855e97917c1d232c8588ba6/Examples/Objective-C/Examples/Others/CustomCells/XLFormCustomCell.m) .. Just override this in your custom cell class i guess.

Comment: thanks for the great advice!! I couldn't find `XLFormCustomCell` but let my cell override `XLFormButtonCell` instead of `XLFormBaseCell` that solved the issue